# how to compare for map a word between 2 string message

Tags: javascript

- I have simple two message(string) and I want to compare 2 words "coffee" , "tea" ,if in the first message
  have the word "coffee" and second message must to have "tea" on that. 
  ** If it be this and all other word same, it true. 
  ** can show if in these 2 word have difference on that point
  ** if other word in message difference it false
- how to check if the total the word define equal
- how to loop checking one by one

var message 1 = "He like to drink a coffee very much, he always drink a coffee in the moring and in the afternoon for some they he drink coffee more one cup. If he have to work over time he have to drink a coffee again. In a month he drank coffee a lot cup.";

var message 2 = "He like to drink a tea very much, he always drink a tea in the moring and in the afternoon for some they he drink juice more one cup. If he have to work over time he have to drink a tea again. In a month he drank tea a lot cup.";

```
function compare(message_1,message_2)
{   
}
```

it's good if show result like this.

..
He like to drink a **coffee** very much, he always drink a **coffee** in the morning and in the afternoon for some they he drink *!!!juice!!!* more one cup. If he have to work over time he have to drink a **coffee** again. In a *!!!year!!!* he drank **coffee** a lot cup.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
var message = prompt("");
if(message == "coffee"){
alert("He like to drink a coffee very much, he always drink a coffee in the moring and in the afternoon for some they he drink coffee more one cup. If he have to work over time he have to drink a coffee again. In a month he drank coffee a lot cup.")
}else if(message == "tea"){
alert( "He like to drink a tea very much, he always drink a tea in the moring and in the afternoon for some they he drink juice more one cup. If he have to work over time he have to drink a tea again. In a month he drank tea a lot cup.")
}else{
alert('choose tea or coffee')
}
```